# What is a frame in Chrome browser extensions?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, browser-extension

In the extension API, there is a parameter for the manifest.json called [`all_frames`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/content_scripts/)

> Optional. Defaults to false, meaning that only the top frame is
> matched.
>
> If specified true, it will inject into all frames, even if the frame
> is not the topmost frame in the tab. Each frame is checked
> independently for URL requirements, it will not inject into child
> frames if the URL requirements are not met.

I'm familiar with frames as in frames per second, but that doesn't seem to apply here. What is meant by "only the top frame is matched"? Is "frame" the same thing as tab?

Comment: Frames in this context means any [`<iframe>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) elements within the page

Comment: See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webNavigation/getFrame

Comment: what about service workder, is it right to say it runs in its own "frame" ?

Comment: what does chatgpt say?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Frames exist inside a Tab and Frame IDs are unique within a tab.

As from the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/webNavigation/):

> Frames within a tab can be identified by a frame ID. The frame ID of
> the main frame is always 0, the ID of child frames is a positive
> number. Once a document is constructed in a frame, its frame ID
> remains constant during the lifetime of the document.

```
getAllFrames
chrome.webNavigation.getAllFrames(
  details: object,
  callback?: function,
)
```

This retrieves information about all frames of a given tab.